# How do I auto-refresh / auto-rebuild my Maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

This is the coding experience I'm looking for in Eclipse...

1. Write some code.
2. Save the file.
3. Refresh my web page.
4. View the changes I made.

From what I can see, Eclipse has a "Build Automatically" option and it seems to work fine. However, each time I save my changes I have to click "Terminate" and then "Run" inside Eclipse to restart the Maven server and see my changes. It's only a couple of clicks but it feels this should happen automatically.

How do I make the Maven restart happen automatically inside Eclipse?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh maven every time you make changes? Typically this is only done to update project dependencies that don't change that often (in my experience).

Comment: If I don't restart Maven then I never see my code changes reflected. Example, I have some SQL statements in my project. I update those queries and the website just keeps using the old queries...until I restart Maven.  Restarting Maven seems to be the only way my recent code changes get reflected.

Comment: Maven is not a server. I'm assuming you mean you're using maven to run your project WAR in Tomcat or Jetty, right?

Comment: This sounds more like a cache issue. I would check your server configuration settings on the eclipse server tab. I seriously doubt this has anything to do with Maven.

Comment: Ah, forgive my ignorance on this. I'm new to Java development. All I know is that Eclipse calls my project a Maven project. Now that you've called my attention to it, I see it is indeed a Jetty server that is acting as the web server.

Answer (score 0):

To get hot deployment of changes in Eclipse you need to use [Eclipse Web Tools (WTP)](https://eclipse.org/webtools/) for running your WAR, not Maven. You define a server and set it up so that your project is deployed in that server instance. Then you can configure it so that changes made in the app trigger a hot re-deployment.

Alternatively, if you want to use Jetty to run/test locally (my personal preference), use the [Eclipse Jetty launcher](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-jetty) plugin.

For either of these to work you'll need to be using [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) and the https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/ plugin and have your project configured as a Maven project in Eclipse.